How to replace a block of consecutive values if the values immediately before and after the block are the same in spark?
I am new to Spark and am facing a problem that I have been struggling to solve for several days. I have not been able to find a solution yet. Answers in Spark Java or Scala would be appreciated. My dataset is as given below.



Instance
time
power_source




I1
2024-09-01-00:00:00
Electricity


I1
2024-09-01-00:15:00
Error


I1
2024-09-01-00:30:00
Error


I1
2024-09-01-00:45:00
Error


I1
2024-09-01-01:00:00
Electricity


I1
2024-09-01-01:15:00
Error


I1
2024-09-01-01:30:00
Battery


I1
2024-09-01-01:45:00
Error


I1
2024-09-01-02:00:00
Battery



Now, if the value below and above a block of Error is same, then I want to replace all Error with that value. Also, the replacement operation should be done by partitioning on Instance. So my output should look like below.



Instance
time
power_source




I1
2024-09-01-00:00:00
Electricity


I1
2024-09-01-00:15:00
Electricity


I1
2024-09-01-00:30:00
Electricity


I1
2024-09-01-00:45:00
Electricity


I1
2024-09-01-01:00:00
Electricity


I1
2024-09-01-01:15:00
Error <-- value above and below this is not same, hence not replaced


I1
2024-09-01-01:30:00
Battery


I1
2024-09-01-01:45:00
Battery


I1
2024-09-01-02:00:00
Battery



Then I want to find the total count, maximum and minimum consecutive count of each power source for each Instance. So from above output it should be:
Electricity -> total count: 5, max consecutive: 5, min consecutive: 5
Battery -> total count: 3, max consecutive: 3, min consecutive: 3
I couldn't solve the first part but for second part (finding count), I plan to collect the power_source in a list across each Instance and then pass it on to a UDF to find the count.

One approach I can think of is an use of groupby with a custom function to operate on the grouped values.

You will group on instance and order by time.

Send the grouped data to a function, which can iterate on the values of power source.

In first iteration over the values , we will have to find if the error block is within same values or not. you can easily do this using array functions.

If yes the error block is enclosed within same values, You just have to iterate over the values again ,and update all the error values with whatever is enclosing the error values.


I know it's not the best approach, But based on my experiance this should work. will update if I think of anything else.
